# Regex to extract usernames/names from a string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have strings that includes names and sometime a username in a string followed by a datetime stamp:

```
GN1RLWFH0546-2020-04-10-18-09-52-563945.txt
JOHN-DOE-2020-04-10-18-09-52-563946t64.txt
DESKTOP-OHK45JO-2020-04-09-02-27-11-451975.txt
```

I want to extract the usernames from this string:

```
GN1RLWFH0546
JOHN-DOE   
DESKTOP-OHK45JO
```

I have tried different regex patterns the closest I came to extract was following:

```
GN1RLWFH0546
DESKTOP
JOHN
```

Using the following regex pattern:

```
names = re.search(r"\(?([0-9A-Za-z]+)\)?", agent_str)
print(names.group(1))
```

Comment: Have you thought about mathing the timestamp first and the subtract the pattern to get the usernames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get all text up to the first occurrence of `-`+digits+`-`:

```
^.*?(?=-\d+-)
```

If the number must be exactly 4 digits (say, if it is a year), then replace `+` with `{4}`:

```
^.*?(?=-\d{4}-)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zhYgGs/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=-\d+-)` - up to the first occurrence of `-` and 1+ digits (or, if `\d{4}` is used, exactly four digits) and then `-` (this part is not added to the match value as the positive lookahead is a non-consuming pattern).

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FnX2db):

```
import re
strs = ["GN1RLWFH0546-2020-04-10-18-09-52-563945.txt", "JOHN-DOE-2020-04-10-18-09-52-563946t64.txt", "DESKTOP-OHK45JO-2020-04-09-02-27-11-451975.txt"]
rx = re.compile(r"^.*?(?=-\d+-)")
for s in strs:
  m = rx.search(s)
  if m:
    print("{} => '{}'".format(s, m.group()))
```

Output:

```
GN1RLWFH0546-2020-04-10-18-09-52-563945.txt => 'GN1RLWFH0546'
JOHN-DOE-2020-04-10-18-09-52-563946t64.txt => 'JOHN-DOE'
DESKTOP-OHK45JO-2020-04-09-02-27-11-451975.txt => 'DESKTOP-OHK45JO'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest stripping off the trailing content you don't want, leaving behind what you do want:

```
inp = "GN1RLWFH0546-2020-04-10-18-09-52-563945.txt"
out = re.sub(r'-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*$', '', inp)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
GN1RLWFH0546
```

See the regex demo below.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

How about the following regex: `(.*)-\d{4}-`.  This matches anything followed by a hyphen, four digits, and another hyphen.

Using the above regex the first group is the username, ala:

```
import re
agent_str = 'DESKTOP-OHK45JO-2020-04-09-02-27-11-451975.txt'
names = re.search(r'(.*)-\d{4}-', agent_str)
print(names.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

agent_str = ["GN1RLWFH0546-2020-04-10-18-09-52-563945.txt", "JOHN-DOE-2020-04-10-18-09-52-563946t64.txt", "DESKTOP-OHK45JO-2020-04-09-02-27-11-451975.txt"]

for sub in agent_str:
    names = re.search(r"([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)(\-[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)?", sub)
    print(names.group())
```